# Combobox DisplayMemberPath with alias column name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Can `DisplayMemberPath` be used with an alias column name.

Code to populate `ComboBox`:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = MainWindow.DatabaseConnection();
try
{
     conn.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

string sql = @"SELECT CameraID, 
               Vendor.VendorName || ' ' || Camera.Model AS CameraName, 
               Camera.Active 
               FROM Camera 
               JOIN Vendor USING (VendorID) 
               ORDER BY CameraName";

SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Camera");
SQLiteDataAdapter ad = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);
ad.Fill(dataTable);
_dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
comboBoxTableEditMount.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxTableEditMount" 
Grid.Column="2" 
Grid.Row="8" 
DisplayMemberPath="CameraName"
SelectedValue="{Binding CameraID}"
SelectedValuePath="MountID"
Style="{DynamicResource ComboboxData}" 
Width="135" 
Margin="-80,0,0,0" />
```

The `ComboBox` is not listing any items. If I change the `DisplayMemberPath` to `CameraID` the numbers are displayed.

Comment: You should start looking into binding error log messages in output windows.

Comment: What happened to the previous comments?

Comment: Probably deleted by the owner

Comment: It happens when one realize that his/her proposed answer is not viable. back to your issue,  do you get some binding error message from output when you do debug?

Comment: I understand. I found the problem! I was reloading the ComboBox at a place where I should have commented out the old code. I don't know how I missed this, especially with all the debugging I did. Thanks everyone for helping. And I apologize for the false alarm. Bob K.